# Using Raspberry Pi + Webcam to record video in python, but sometimes camera does not turn on/off as I expected

Tags: python, opencv, video, webcam

I am trying to using Raspberry Pi + webcam (logitech) to record video, but there is a problem at the first step... I would like to male the webcam turned on when needed, and turned off otherwise, however when I try

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if cap.isOpened() != True:
    cap.open(0)
```

the webcam still didn't turn on sometimes...
so I would like to know if someone knows the solution, I will appreciate you!
Thanks!

Comment: Disconnect the power of the USB port, the application's upgrade errors are exhausted (which must be a separate process), give the power of the USB port again. or access the USB device through the system because you need to specify the device's initial parameters. Some devices can initially request work settings (communication speed, image size (resolution), light correction, color correction, focus ratio, etc.--Read the technical document of the device).  Resetting the device port is not resetting the device. What situation does it react to?

Comment: Do you mean that I need to change some parameters of the setting of the camera?

Comment: Those parameters are not setting action(this is `initial action`). You must write this information to the relevant data addresses of the camera. You must also close and reopen the kernel drive each time you connect. Almost all USB connections start with "Reset the USB connection + device". This allows you to terminate the previous connection to your device and assign new parameters. **Closing access does not mean shutting down the bus !** If you examine the PYUSB or the product's driver, you may have an idea of how to connect your device.

Answer (score 0):

try releasing it first, before opening it:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if cap.isOpened() != True:
    cap.release()
    cap.open(0)
```

Comment: It seems that problem still not exist... is there any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that problem still exist?